# Nginx bottleneck at 55k Requests per Second but server still has plenty to give

Tags: performance, nginx, openresty

So basically I have setup Nginx OpenResty and tried to optimize the config for maximum performance / requests .

The server can clearly handle a lot without even blinking, but it seems like after around 55k Request per Second Nginx won't establish any more connections, as shown per stats.

I am using Luameter to get my readings, and by stressing my server using cloud platform doing 50k Requests per second or 100k Requests per second never returns more then the 50k Requests from Nginx stats.

The server has a full 1gbps port but never sends more then 330mbps output when being stressed. It also has a SSD HDD.

Cpu is at 45% when being hit with 100k Requests per second.

Ulimit is unlimited and ulimit -n 999999

Here s a snippet of my nginx config :

```
user  nobody; worker_processes  8; worker_rlimit_nofile 262144; error_log            logs/error.log crit;

events {
worker_connections  100000;
use epoll;
multi_accept on; }

http {

open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s; open_file_cache_valid 30s;  
open_file_cache_min_uses 2; open_file_cache_errors on;
```

How could I possibly increase this limit considering there's still room to work with in what comes to server resources ?

Thanks

Comment: Linux 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is TCP/IP stack configuration problem. Check this out: https://www.percona.com/live/mysql-conference-2015/sites/default/files/slides/all_your_iops_are_belong_to_usPLMCE2015.pdf

Nevertheless don't expect too much out of single box, spread the load.

**UPDATE**

Nginx configuration can be reviewed according to official performance tuning recommendation: https://www.nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/

Comment: Hum thanks for the suggestion, but isn't the article you linked mainly related to HDD IOPS ?

THe Hdd was my first thought for what might be causing the bottleneck, however 2 things :

1) I m not getting my stats from logs, this is using lua module and the readings take place in the log processing stage so it s not actually directly querying the log files

2) When server is being stressed IOstat doesn t show any significant Hdd activity

Comment: you mentioned that there is network throttling which is results of inefficient TCP/IP stack configuration, older versions of irqbalance or RSP (receive packet steering) is disabled. This article which is actually slides are not about IOPS but rather about performance issues relate to network configuration. What kind of response you serve to?

Comment: mikhailov thanks that makes sense.

I am basically serving either a static .txt file or just querying a non existing url with 404 reply, just wanna see how much the server can handle in terms of Raw requests without other limiting factors.

I guess optimizing TCP/IP stack config will be the next logical step then, time for some googling.

Comment: @Rdang, exactly, in case of absence of backend processing, your starting point can be file system mount option access tuning, *kernel upgrade* (as significant impact option) and TCP/IP buffer settings which are covered in those slides pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Further to mikhailov's comment, this specifically helps spread the IRQ load of the network which may help in your situation:

```
echo f > /sys/class/net/eth0/queues/rx-0/rps_cpus
```

Comment: Yea this is just an E3-1230 V3

Comment: So that makes a significant difference especially with old kernel